# Request for application tags (Flask/Redis)

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my DevOps stack exchange post: [Should worker processes of web applications be placed in separate containers?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3086/5879)

*Flask* and *Redis* constitute important aspects of the question which is why I would like to requests that they be added.

Related: [Request and question about application tags (gunicorn/flask) in web applications](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250/5879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel it would help define the question, which is more about multiple process in a docker container.

The question itself could be applied to other tools/frameworks than flask and with other back-ends than redis and the answer would be the same.

There's no need for too narrow tagging of a question IMHO.

Comment: Valid point. To close the question should I accept your answer or delete the question?

Comment: I'm not a source of truth by myself, wait a little to see if community agree or voice another opinion on this before taking any action :)

Comment: @Moritz I agree with Tensibai. But, if you think that adding more tags would help the post or the site (for easy search), then, by all means, we can add them. No problem :)

Comment: I am open to the tag policy. I did not find any reference, so I am only relying on my previous meta post. If both of you think they are superfluous, it makes sense due to your greater amount of experience